# withCriteria fetch list of associated objects

Tags: grails, criteria

I'm new to Grails and finding it difficult to get my head around db criterias.

Can anyone help with the following:

This is my domain structure:

-- Comment
   --CommentGroups
     -- Comments

So my domain classes look like (Simplified):

```
class Comment {
    String commentTitle
    String comment
    CommentGroup commentGroup   
    static hasMany = [commentGroups:CommentGroup]
    static constraints = {
        commentGroup nullable:true
    }
}

class CommentGroup{
    String groupTitle
    static constraints = {
        groupTitle blank:true, nullable:true
    }
}
```

So I have comments that can have many commentGroups that in turn can have many comments, but I do not have a hasMany Comments on my commentGroup. Instead I associate a comment to a group by assigning a commentGroup to the comment.

This is saving to the MySQL DB correctly, and I have managed to pull back the comments with commentGroups with the following code:

```
    def testimonialList = Comment.withCriteria {
        eq 'approved', true
        isNull 'commentGroup'
        order('dateCreated', 'desc')
        order('displayPriority','desc')
        maxResults max
        firstResult offset
    }
```

What I need to achieve now is pull back all Comments for each of the current Comment CommentGroups by match the current Comment CommentGroup with the associated Comment CommentGroup and hold them in a list under each CommentGroup.

So I end up with a object structure similar to:

```
Comment
   CommentGroup1
      Comment1
      Comment2
      Comment3
   CommentGroup2
      Comment1
      Comment2
      Comment3
```

Can anyone help me finish off my criteria query to achieve this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the result you're looking for you'll need a different approach.

## The problem

You described the domain model as: **Comment-*1*-----*n*--CommentGroup-*1*-----*n*--Comment**

If that were the case you'd be able to achieve your goal quite easily. But in fact what you have is: **Comment-*1*-----*n*--CommentGroup-*n*-----*1*--Comment**

Since the `CommentGroup` doesn't have a reference to it's `Comment`s it's challenging to go from `CommentGroup` to `Comment`.

## Working toward a solution

For a given `CommentGroup` you can get its `Comment`s like this:

```
def comments = Comment.withCriteria {
    eq('commentGroup', commentGroup)
}
```

If you have a list of `CommentGroup`s then you can get all of their `Comment`s like this:

```
def comments = Comment.withCriteria {
    inList('commentGroup', commentGroups)
}
```

So you'd have to:

1. Run a query to get the list of `Comment`s you're interested in.
2. Use the `.commentGroups` property of those `Comments` to get a list of `CommentGroup`s.
3. Run a second query to get the `Comment`s for the `CommentGroup`s.
4. Piece everything together into the structure you need; probably using nested `Map`s.

The first three steps would look something like this:

```
def comments = Comment.withCriteria {
    eq 'approved', true
    isNull 'commentGroup'
    ...
}

def commentGroups = comments*.commentGroups

def comments = Comment.withCriteria {
    inList('commentGroup', commentGroups)
}
```

## A better approach

It would be much simpler to create the domain model you described, with associations appropriate for this purpose:

```
class Comment {
    String commentTitle
    String comment
    static belongsTo = CommentGroup
    static hasMany = [commentGroups:CommentGroup]
    static constraints = {
        commentGroup nullable:true
    }
}

class CommentGroup{
    String groupTitle
    static hasMany = [comments: Comment]
    static constraints = {
        groupTitle blank:true, nullable:true
    }
}
```

With this model, once you have a `Comment` you can get its `CommentGroup`s and *its* `Comment`s

```
def otherComments = comment.commentGroups*.comments
```

But to get closer to the output you're looking for you'd be better off with HQL. That's because a criteria query cannot *project* the root entity. For example, if you query for `Comment`s like this: `Comment.withCriteria {...}` you can either return those `Comment`s (the root entity, which is the default behaviour) or, you can *project* properties of `Comment`. It's either/or. But HQL does not have this restriction.

```
def hql = """
SELECT   c, cgs, cs
FROM     Comment as c
         INNER JOIN c.commentGroups as cgs
         INNER JOIN cgs.comments as cs
WHERE    c.approved = true
         // Ignoring, c.commentGroup IS NULL, because it doesn't make sense.
ORDER BY c.dateCreated DESC, c.displayPriority DESC
"""

def result = Comment.executeQuery(hql, null, [maxResults: max])
```

The result would look something like this:

```
[
    [Comment 1, CommentGroup 1, Comment x],
    [Comment 1, CommentGroup 1, Comment y],
    [Comment 1, CommentGroup 1, Comment z],
    [Comment 1, CommentGroup 2, Comment a],
    [Comment 1, CommentGroup 2, Comment b],
    [Comment 1, CommentGroup 2, Comment c],
    [Comment 2, ...],
]
```

Basically it's the structure you asked for, but flattened as a query result set.

I have an [article](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/gorm-for-sqladdicts-from-clause/) on how to query GORM associations where I demonstrate the impact associations have on the queries you can create. I think you'll find it helpful in learning about criteria queries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason I included a commentGroup IS NULL is to prevent retrieving the sub comments as a parent comment. This is the only distinguishing identifier between a main comment and a sub comment so surely this still has to be included in the top level query?

Comment: No because the parent comment is returned in the first column and the sub comments in the third. What you might need is `c != cs` in the where clause to skip rows where a parent comment is the same as a sub comment.

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll try this out but I'm still confused as the first column looks like it will traverse all comments which will include all comments wouldn't it? Therefore you will get the subcomment and comments in column 1 wouldn't you. Maybe I'm over complicating this. I'm just trying to understand it. Sorry if I'm being a pain.

Comment: Oh maybe I'm thinking that you were basing this on my old domains. I guess you're saying that I need to change my domains as you have suggested and then the hql will work.

Comment: Ooh yes. That's true. You're not being a pain. I understand you better now. OK, with comment groups, as I understand them, there's no notion of a sub comment. The groups are merely labels, they don't establish a hierarchy. In a hierarchy a comment would have a parent (a single group) and requires a different domain model.